# Regression weighted by response variable

Tags: regression, weights

Is it a valid a approach to weight a regression by the sqrt of the response variable to improve model under-prediction?

I am predicting maximum cyanobacterial cover (%) for rivers from 19 env. variables using BRT model (library gbm) with a logit transformed response and weighted by sqrt(response+0.01). Which does a suspiciously amazing job with a R^2 of 0.94 of predicted vs. observed. The issue is by weighting cases by the response there is some kind of response information on the right hand side of the formula, i.e y ~ x|y. Unweighted or weighting by n models result in considerably underestimated predictions. Any insights much appreciated.

Comment: It would be a rather unusual thing to do (with some consequences for the usual inference). Can you say more about what's going on and how you came up with this? (i.e. there may well be a more typical thing to do that achieves a similar end)

Comment: Thanks. I am predicting maximum cyanobacterial cover (%) for rivers from 19 env. variables using BRT model (library gbm) with a logit transformed response and weighted by sqrt(response+0.01). Which does a suspiciously amazing job with a R^2 of 0.94 of predicted vs. observed.  The issue is by weighting cases by the response there is some kind of response information on the right hand side of the formula, i.e y ~ x|y.  Unweighted or weighting by n results is considerably underestimated predictions. Any insights much appreciated.

Comment: This seems like very important information to include in your post.